# Tkinter menubutton error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very confused about this widget, can someone fix it ?

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
mytext = StringVar()
mytext.set("DEFAULT")
def test_function(evt):
  mb.menu.delete(0, END)
  for i in range(20):
    mb.menu.add("command", label='%s'%i, command= lambda : mytext.set("%s"%i))


mb=  Menubutton (master, text="Test", relief=RAISED )
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu
mb.bind('<Button-1>', test_function)
mb.grid(row = 0, column=1)
Label(master, textvariable=mytext).grid(row = 0, column=0)

master.mainloop()
```

`mytext` always show the end of the list when selected the button how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mb.menu.add("command", label='%s'%i, command= lambda : mytext.set("%s"%i))`

The `i` in the `command` lambda here binds to the last value that `i` had, rather than the value it had when you called `add`.

You can trick it into binding early by making it a default argument:

`mb.menu.add("command", label='%s'%i, command= lambda i=i: mytext.set("%s"%i))`